# Bitwise OR between two strings in python

Tags: python

I want to apply bitwise OR between two strings without using for loop. For example;

```
first_string = "0101"
second_string = "1010"
result = "1111"
```

Is there a way to calculate the word without breaking it apart? so i mean fastest way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, you can first use the int function and give it a base:

```
a = int('0101', 2)
b = int('1111', 2)
```

And then you can do the or operation and convert back with format:

```
c = a | b 
print("{0:b}".format(c))
```